# Can we quotient a set $A$ by another set $B$ such that $B\not\subset A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

I'm reading Ash's Basic Abstract Algebra. Here:

> [image]

I'm a little bit confused. When we restrict the map $\pi: G\to G/N$, we get the map $\pi_0:H\to H/(H\cap N)$, right? Assuming this is true, I don't see how the image of $\pi_0$ is what is given in there.

In $\pi_0$, $H$ is partitioned in the classes $H\cap N, h_1(H \cap N )\dots$, I think we would need a partition such as $N,h_1 N, h_2 N, \dots$, in this case I guess we should have $\pi_0:H\to H/N$ but I don't know if this makes sense because $N$ could have elements not in $H$.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? I'm not sure where the confusion is coming from, and need for a map from $H$ to $H/N$

Comment: When we restrict $\pi:G\to G/N$ to $H$ we get $\pi_0:H\to G/N$ defined by $\pi_0(h)=hN$ for every $h\in H$.

Comment: @SMM This makes much more sense, I can finish the proof now. But out of curiosity,  can we have something as my question?

Comment: @BillyRubina In general, you can quotient a set $A$ by an equivalence relation on $A$. I don't really see what does it mean to quotient $A$ even by its subset $B$.

Comment: @SMM I mean: quotient $A$ by $B$ such that $B\not\subset A$. I guess this would be just the product.